# ST_AsLatLonText returns wrong data

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0, osm2pgsql

I want to list all cities in `lubelskie vovoidenship`, which is relation 130919. 
I also want to get `latLong` data for each city. To perform this I do:

```sql
SELECT 
    name, ST_AsLatLonText(way), place 
FROM 
    planet_osm_point
WHERE 
    place IN ('city', 'town', 'village', 'hamlet')
    AND ST_Contains((SELECT way FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE osm_id = -130919), way)
```

Query runs ok, but problem lays within the results. 
For example:

```
...
"Lublin";"15°1'48.000"S 45°23'24.000"E";"city"
...
```

The coordinates for **every** city are **wrong**. What should I do?

**UPDATE**

Data is imported using `osm2pgsql`:

```
osm2pgsql -U postgres -W -d gis2 --create ~/Pobrane/poland-latest.osm
```

Data downloaded from: http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/poland.html

Result using `ST_AsEWKT()`:

```
"Lublin";"SRID=900913;POINT(2512485.39 6665744.97)";"city"
```

Comment: What's the CRS of your geometries?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. It might help if you expanded your question with how you imported this (presumably with osm2pgsql, but what arguments did you use). Also, can you show what happens if you can ```SELECT name, ST_AsEWKT(way))``` and show a little data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ST_AsLatLonText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_AsLatLonText.html) documentation says:

> It is assumed the point is in a lat/lon projection. The X (lon) and Y
>   (lat) coordinates are normalized in the output to the "normal" range
>   (-180 to +180 for lon, -90 to +90 for lat).

So you are seeing your point (in 900913) "wrapped" around until it eventually gets into the normal range.

To see your positions display properly as Latitude / Longitude text, you need to transform your data from 900913 (google mercator) SRID to 4326 (wgs84) before passing it through ST_AsLatLonText. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    name, ST_AsLatLonText(ST_Transform(way, 4326)), place 
FROM 
    planet_osm_point
WHERE 
    place IN ('city', 'town', 'village', 'hamlet')
    AND ST_Contains((SELECT way FROM planet_osm_polygon WHERE osm_id = -130919), way)
```